# Heroku - Run Heroku CLI commands from web dashboard

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

Is it possible to run `heroku`-cli-commands like `heroku regions` from the Heroku Dashboard?

I tried to run those in the `console`, but it did not work..

[image: Excerpt of the Heroku website, showing the console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [heroku explanation page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1137), as well as [the appearance of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w96UQ.png), it seems that you can only run commands that start with `heroku run` (Example: `npm start`).

> That means you can run commands there for the app, and heroku will pass them to it. Like you could run if the app was running on your computer. But do not run regular heroku cli commands, for example install an add-on, through the dashboard on the website, but only through [heroku cli](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli)